# How to bring Illustrator CS6 file to Illustrator CC and still use CSS Extraction

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, mockup, front-end-development, wireframing

If I've begun a project in Illustrator CS6 (a high fidelity mockup), can I later copy and paste this content into Illustrator CC and still expect to be able to use CC's `CSS Extraction` functionality on this content?

Everything I've found on the net so far has been about bringing CC files down into CS6 - I'm trying to do the reverse to reap the full benefits of the great tools in CC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally it is **never** an issue to open older files with newer versions.

I would not copy/paste, I'd **open** the legacy file. But you shouldn't have any issue moving *forward* in versions. It's only *backwards* that may present problems.

Adobe doesn't often just outright kill support for features in older versions of the same application. They may change how a feature functions, but when they do that they also build in conversions for the old method. (for example, Gaussian Blur which changed in CS6... but still sees older versions of the Gaussian Blur if they exist).